# I need a javascript that can extract specific text from a PDF

Tags: javascript, acrobat, text-extraction

I work as legal support in litigation. I am not that clued up on scripting, but have managed to adapt a few google searches to perform various tasks for in Adobe.

What I need is help with what I think should be a simple script to read through a PDF and extract Document IDs. They are enclosed in square brackets, so I just need to extract all text between square brackets to a text or CSV file. I have tried using the ChatGPT bot but that hasnt been very successful. This is the code it has given me

```
// Open the PDF file
var filePath = "/path/to/your/file.pdf";
var doc = app.open(filePath);

// Get the number of pages
var numPages = doc.numPages;

// Create an array to hold the results
var results = [];

// Loop through each page and extract text between square brackets
for (var i = 0; i < numPages; i++) {
  var page = doc.getPageNthWordQuads(i);

  for (var j = 0; j < page.length; j++) {
    var word = page[j];
    var text = word[4];

    // Check if the text is between square brackets
    if (text.startsWith("[") && text.endsWith("]")) {
      // Remove the brackets and add the text to the results array
      results.push(text.slice(1, -1));
    }
  }
}

// Save the results to a text file
var outputPath = "/path/to/your/output/file.txt";
var outputFile = new File(outputPath);
outputFile.open("w");
outputFile.write(results.join("\n"));
outputFile.close();

// Close the PDF file
doc.close();
```

I ran the script, with my file directory, not the placeholder in the script, but nothing happened. No error or anything

I am using a work PC so I cant install python or any other program, hence the need for Java or possibly powershell if that will work

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I realised i could do this using the Evermap plugin. Highlight text by pattern - [(.*?)], then extract highlighted text.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the entire for loop and just use a regular expression with `String.match()`:

```js
const data = "This is the text ofa pdf file [documentid1] and [documentid2].";
const matches = data.match(/(?<=\[).*?(?=\])/gs);
console.log(matches);
```